# An identity involving expectations of products of the normal CDF

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $\Phi$ be the standard normal CDF and let $X$ be standard normal. Suppose $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3$ are positive constants. Show that $$ E \Bigl[\Phi\Bigl(\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}X\Bigr) \Phi\Bigl(\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_3}X\Bigr)\Bigr] + E \Bigl[\Phi\Bigl(\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}X\Bigr) \Phi\Bigl(\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_3}X\Bigr)\Bigr] + E \Bigl[\Phi\Bigl(\frac{\sigma_3}{\sigma_2}X\Bigr) \Phi\Bigl(\frac{\sigma_3}{\sigma_1}X\Bigr)\Bigr] = 1. $$ Numerical calculations show that this should be true for arbitrary constants. Each expectation can be obviously expressed as probabilities involving three standard normals but this does not seem to help. I assume I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Your description is confusing.  Expectations have random variables as arguments.  Your arguments are distribution functions, not random variables.

Comment: In reply to me “uniform distribution” tag being edited out, I should have pointed out that if $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2 = \sigma_3$, this becomes $3E(U^2)$ for $U$ standard uniform and the identity holds.

Comment: @herbsteinberg these are distribution functions evaluated at random variables, which makes them random variables themselves.